# Swapping token with fee in solidity fails on safeTransfer

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ganache, uniswap

I want to have a smart contract on Ethereum that does ETH->token swapping. I got that working for 'normal' tokens, but I just can't get it to work with the following token at address 0x535659CB81ad02f6b015050Df79E194F9eE66847.

The swapping code:

```
  address private constant WETH_ADDRESS = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
  address private constant UNISWAPFACTORY = 0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f;
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;

  function swapViaRouter(address tokenAddress) external payable {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = WETH_ADDRESS;
        path[1] = tokenAddress;

        IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS).swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{
            value: msg.value
        }(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 150);
    }
```

I get the error 'UniswapV2: TRANSFER_FAILED'. That message comes from the token itself, when safeTransfer fails. Which is the default safeTransfer from Uniswap:

```
    bytes4 private constant SELECTOR =
        bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));

    function _safeTransfer(
        address token,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) external payable {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(
            abi.encodeWithSelector(SELECTOR, to, value)
        );

        require(
            success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))),
            "UniswapV2: TRANSFER_FAILED"
        );
    }
```

The uniswaprouter interface:

```
interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function factory() external view returns (address);

    function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] calldata path)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function getAmountsIn(uint256 amountOut, address[] calldata path)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint256 amountADesired,
        uint256 amountBDesired,
        uint256 amountAMin,
        uint256 amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    )
        external
        returns (
            uint256 amountA,
            uint256 amountB,
            uint256 liquidity
        );

    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint256 amountTokenDesired,
        uint256 amountTokenMin,
        uint256 amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    )
        external
        payable
        returns (
            uint256 amountToken,
            uint256 amountETH,
            uint256 liquidity
        );

    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint256 liquidity,
        uint256 amountAMin,
        uint256 amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256 amountA, uint256 amountB);

    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint256 liquidity,
        uint256 amountTokenMin,
        uint256 amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256 amountToken, uint256 amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint256 amountOut,
        uint256 amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactETHForTokens(
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapTokensForExactETH(
        uint256 amountOut,
        uint256 amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactTokensForETH(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapETHForExactTokens(
        uint256 amountOut,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external payable;
}
```

Swapping does work for other tokens like 0x5026F006B85729a8b14553FAE6af249aD16c9aaB, that don't have fee.

I use ganache-cli to fork the mainnet at latest block. I also tried calling the swap function inside the pairContract directly but that gave me the same error.

I did a swap via the uniswap interface on the actual mainnet and that just worked. I also checked if there are other smart contracts swapping that token and there are.

I'm now struggling for a few days, but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.I hope someone can point me towards something obvious or less obvious.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was ganache-cli, on a real mainnet it just worked.